# Singular homology - take every possible map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading singular homology in Hatcher. Let $X$ be a topological space. We let $C_n(X)$ be generated by singular $n$-simplicies $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$.

What I don't understand is, what collection of $n$-simplicies do we want? Do we just take every single possible distinct map $\Delta^n\to X$? Say I am mapping $3$-simplicies into the space $X=\Delta^3$, do I not have uncountably many choices of maps?

I can see in this way why the point space has a single singular $n$-cell for each $n$, since we must map each simplex to the point, if we are taking every possible map.

Comment: Yes, all such continuous maps.  It will be extraordinarily many.  An equivalence relation will take care of that.

Comment: @Randall What is the equivalence relation? Or you mean when we take homology it doesn't matter, since we identify the faces of the simplicies with the standard simplex?

Comment: Yes, forming the homology groups.

Comment: @Randall In some sense it seems easy to work out what the maps in the kernel of the boundary map are, at least for small $n$.  What are we really identifying when we quotient the image though?

Comment: @Randall I guess I should formulate my question more carefully, in a distinct MSE question.

Answer (score 4):

Historically homology groups were first defined for *simplicial complexes* which are purely combinatorial entities. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology.

Let us consider your example $\Delta^3$. We obtain *one* generator of the *non-oriented* simplicial chain complex in dimension $3$ resp. *two* generators of the *oriented* simplicial chain complex in dimension $3$. This is a very effective method to associate chain complexes and homology groups to simplicial complexes.

What is the relationship between topological spaces and simplicial complexes? Each simplicial complex $K$ has a *geometric realization* $\lvert K \rvert$ which is a topological space consisting of Euclidean simplices which are convex  hulls of points in general position in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (each combinatorial $n$-simplex which is a finite set of vertices is realized as a Euclidean simplex, and these Euclidean simplices are glued together by the corresponding combinatorial incidences of the faces). But certainly not every space is the geometric realization of simplicial complex. Moreover, two non-isomorphic simplicial complexes may have homeomorphic geometric realizations - are their homology groups isomorphic ("topological invariance of simplicial homology")? It was discovered that this question cannot be answered by purely combinatorial methods. This was the origin of singular homology. A *singular  simplex* in a space $X$ is any map $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X$. In general this produces uncountably many singular  simplices (even for the simplest spaces). The resulting chain complexes are very big, but if you go to homology groups the size massively collapses. In fact, the singular homology groups of the geometric realization $\lvert K \rvert $ of a simplicial complex $K$ are isomorphic to the simplicial homology groups of $K$. This proves the topological invariance of simplicial homology and provides a method to effectively compute the homology groups of *polyhedra* (spaces $X$ which have *triangulations*, i.e. admit a homeomorphism $h ; X \to \lvert K \rvert$ where $K$ is simplicial complex).

Singular homology is excellent because it is conceptually simple. It is defined for *any* space without referring to additional structural components (which are usually not uniquely determined by the space itself, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung), even the beginner will easily understand it and topological invariance is obvious from the definition (that is why we take *all* singular simplices and don't *choose* a "smaller" assortment). However, it is practically impossible to *compute* singular homology groups based on the definition of the singular chain complex. But singular homology satisfies the *Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms and we can compute a lot of homology groups using only these axioms. See any book on algebraic topology. The Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms determine homology theories on *finite CW-complexes* uniquely (up to natural isomorphism) by their coefficient groups $H_0(\ast)$ (where $\ast$ is a one-point space). In case of the standard singular homology theory we have $H_0(\ast) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ which is one of the few cases where an effective computation is possible.

My opinion is that the main purpose of singular homology is to establish the *existence* of a homology theory which satisfies the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms and is defined for all topological spaces. There are a lot of other constructions, but they are not simpler and some are only defined on certain classes of spaces. The material distinctions between the various constructions are unveiled only on spaces which are no finite CW-cmplexes, and then it becomes apparent that there are homology theories which perform better then singular homology.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess my concern then is that $C_n(X)$ is usually not a finitely generated object, and the kernel and image of the boundary map will then have to be non-finitely generated. How am I then meant to compute singular homology, even for a circle.

Here it's super easy using simplicial homology, where as you say these coincide anyway. Is singular more to give the theory, than to use to compute?

Comment: True that the chain groups will not be finitely generated, but that will not stop the quotient group from being nice and f.g.

Comment: And, I find singular homology to be wonderful for giving the theory, and I also prefer it computationally, though I admit other more combinatorial models are often simpler.  Singular theory just makes more sense to me.

Comment: Not to hijack this, but I also prefer the singular theory because it works for all spaces with no simplicial/CW/manifold/whatever assumptions.

Comment: @Randall Singular homology is fantastic. I added some remarks to my answer.

Comment: For some more comments on the history, I like to refer to M. Barr, "Oriented singular homology" http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n1/1-01abs.html .

Comment: And for a comparison of other approches to (ordinary) homology see E.G. Sklyarenko's paper  "General homology and cohomology theories. Current state and typical applications" http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=inta&paperid=125&option_lang=eng (from 1989, but by no means outdated).

Comment: @Paul Frost: The link you gave sent me to the Russian version! For another approach, based more on JHC Whitehead's work, see my paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357717300460

Comment: @RonnieBrown Sorry, you can download an English version here: https://slideheaven.com/general-homology-and-cohomology-theories-current-state-and-typical-applications.html